# Page scrolling to top because of jquery Slideshow

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with the page scrolling. Whenever a new image fades in, the page automatically scrolls to top. Please follow the below url.

[Black Toyota](http://blacktoyota.foxqa.com.au/)

I am not using any plugin for the slideshow. Just normal jquery effects. If you need, the code for the gallery will be in scripts/gallery.js. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime your image fades out, the height of #gallery will be set to zero. Give a height to your #gallery.

```
<div id="gallery" style="height:400px">
```